# Which files and settings affect debugging with IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I'm no longer able to debug my Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET solution with IIS Express

I never had issues debugging previously.
Now however, chrome/firefox/IE are unable to connect to localhost. Chrome says: "Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

I have noticed that a different but similar solution still debugs fine, leading me to believe I accidentally screwed up a setting or something.

Which files and settings of the two solutions should I compare in order to see why I'm able to debug one and not the other?

Comment: i believe web.config is the culprit.even i faced this problem.but refreshing web.config  on iis used to solve my problem.not sure what is hapenning behind the screen

Comment: refreshing web.config may have been the solution. I did not try this before restarting my computer (which worked) but the refreshing of web.config on iis may have been the underlying event which solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was restarting my computer. Simply restarting VS did not work. I hate this kind of solution but worked for me. Now it debugs like it used to.